# WooCommerce custom sort (multiple condition)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to sort products on woocommerce in the following conditions:

- unavailable products goes down
- rest of products should be ordered randomly

I tried several ways, but the problem is that randomizing first would be lost after availability order, availability first would be lost after randomizing.

Any solution?

Comment: You want to do that in backend where all products are listed or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add custom sorting option to products. You can do this by this way:

```
function vi_custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $sortby ) {
    $sortby['alphabetical'] = 'Sort by name: custom';
    return $sortby;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'vi_custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'vi_custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );

//Add Alphabetical sorting option to shop page / WC Product Settings
function vi_alphabetical_woocommerce_shop_ordering( $sort_args ) {
  $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? woocommerce_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );

    if ( 'alphabetical' == $orderby_value ) {
        $sort_args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
        $sort_args['order'] = 'asc';
        $sort_args['meta_key'] = '';
    }

    return $sort_args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'vi_alphabetical_woocommerce_shop_ordering' );
```

For products, which are available, you can assign "> 0" values and for all non-available products, you can assign 0. So they will be automatically sorted and will be gone to bottom.